# Detect service shutdown from program

Tags: c#

Is there a way to subscribe to an event when a given service is shut down.

My program occasionally sends commands to a third party windows service, but I have no way of knowing if it is up until I send my request, which then causes an exception since no one is listening.

So I would like to subscribe to an event if possible, to let my user know, that he can't interact with the service at the moment, rather than giving him an error when he tries.

I could have a timer that runs now and then which then checks if the PID is still alive, but I'd rather be told instantly by the OS.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the exception as the indication that the service isn't available?

Comment: You could use `ServiceController` to find your service, and then `WaitForStatus(..)` method to await for the service stop event.

Comment: Is the service run in an own process (you seem to imply that, as you say you thought about checking for the PID), I think the class `Process` has an event Exited.

Comment: That's already available in the `Revocery` tab of a service's properties. You can configure the service to restart once or twice in case of failure, execute a command that may include sending a message or email, or even restart the machine

Comment: Note that `ServiceController.WaitForStatus` simply polls with intervals of 250 ms. The Service Control Manager has no interface for notification, so periodic querying is the best anyone can do. (Assuming you are not willing to go as far as to run a separate command on recovery, which is almost certainly more trouble than it's worth.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I would prefer to warn the user off when things are not as they're supposed to be, rather than give him a slap on the wrist when he tries to do his task. As some of the user's tasks can be critical (life at stake), it is better to warn him.

Comment: @someone I know what the process is called, so I could ask for the PID from that. I will look at the Process class, thanks. Edit: it seems to handle processes _I_ have started. I wonder if it can also attach to an existing one

Comment: Bear in mind that there's no guarantee that the service hasn't stopped in the time between checking it's status and when you send the command.

Comment: ah - yes we can (Process class)

Comment: @b348423 that's not a reliable first response to a fault, **especially* for critical services. What if there's no user, or the user when for coffee? What *can* the user do in case of a problem anyway? Most likely, restart the service. That's why the recovery settings are available in all versions of Windows.

Comment: @b348423 you can't use Process events anyway - a service isn't a simple process. A single process can start *multiple* services. You can use WMI to monitor the status of different services periodically. Services emit *Windows* events too. The Service Start/Stop event are standard for all services. You can subscribe to them and respond. It's also possible to subscribe to events on remote machines. Finally, you can poll for the status of a service with WMI

Comment: Windows Events, WMI are standard manageability mechanisms which means they are always available, for all machines in a domain. They are also used by all monitoring tools and services, including cloud based ones, like Azure Monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this class, if it can be useful to someone else

```
public class ExternalProcessMonitor
{
    Process process;
    Action action;
    string name;

    public ExternalProcessMonitor(string _name, Action _action)
    {
        action = _action;
        name = _name;
    }

    public bool StartMonitor()
    {
        if (process != null)
            process.Exited -= Process_Exited;
        var list = Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(r => r.ProcessName);
        process = Process.GetProcessesByName(name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            process.Exited += Process_Exited;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        return process != null;
    }

    private void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement the list of started services and look for yours in there so that you dont have to send and wait for an error or similar results.

On Windows (7 and higher) you should get an almost complete list of running services by accessing the local or remote servicecontroller.

Here is more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices?view=netframework-4.8

https://answers.unity.com/questions/971269/subscribing-to-event-from-external-class.html